# Left & Right text on title

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to have in a subsection title, a text on the left and another on the right, on the same line.

Here's what I did:

```
 \subsection {Right Text \hfill Left Text}
```

It works fine, but on the summary (table of contents), I also see the right text, but I only want to see the left one.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Your "left" and "right" looked swapped, corrected it.)*

Since you want to see only the left text in the table of contents, you will
have to use the optional argument of `\subsection` command.

```
\subsection[Left Text]{Left Text \hfill Right Text}
```

LaTeX allows you to give an optional extra version of the text which only gets used in the table of contents and any running heads, if they are in effect. This optional alternative heading goes in [square brackets] before the curly braces.

So, as a result of the above usage, 
`Left Text \hfill Right Text` is used as the subsection name in the body text. 
And `Left Text` goes to the table of contents (and in page headings, hope that 
is fine with you.)

Here is the output.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the optional argument

```
\subsection[Right Text Left Text]{Right Text \hfill Left Text}
```